# Unable code fails when initializing mapping of structure

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

Hi I have this structure, but when I call the function `joinLottery`, the mapping for `gamblers[0]` is not updated. Need help to understand why is this happening.

```
struct Gambler {
    uint token;
    uint encRandomNumber;
    bool exist;
    address gamblerAdd;
    address issuer;
}

mapping (int =>  Gambler) public gamblers;
uint public currentNumofGamblers=0;

function joinLottery (uint _token, uint _RandomNumber,
    address _issuer){
    Gambler newGambler = gamblers[int(currentNumofGamblers)]; 
    newGambler.token = _token;
    newGambler.encRandomNumber = _encRandomNumber;
    newGambler.exist = true;
    newGambler.gamblerAdd = msg.sender;
    newGambler.issuer = _issuer;
    currentNumofGamblers++;
    winningNumber = RandomNumber; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is backwards:

```
Gambler newGambler = gamblers[int(currentNumofGamblers)];
```

You can't assign something to newGambler from gamblers if you haven't put anything in gamblers yet.

Try something like:

```
gamblers[int(currentNumofGamblers)] = Gambler(
   _token,
   _encRandomNumber,
   true,
   msg.sender,
   _issuer
);
```